# Geany editor snippet for getting literal %cursor%

Tags: editor, code-snippets, geany

I write a lot of Geany snippets. I would like to add a snippet for %cursor% when writing snippets. I added this in the [Default] snippets:

```
cur=%cursor%
```

Problem being that will evaluate to placing the cursor, so disappears.

I am looking for an escape sequence for the %. I have tried \% and %% but no luck.

```
cur=%curso%cursor%%
```

is an OK workaround as I only need to add an r, but is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The % is escaped with {pc} in Geany, so:

```
cur={pc}cursor{pc}
```

expands to %cursor%

Comment: Can you add a link to where this can be discovered (as there could be other things that need to be escaped)?

Comment: [template-wildcards](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#template-wildcards) on geany manual